# Generate certificates with Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2, azure-keyvault

I am not a professional with certificates, however, I am trying to understand how to get this working with Azure Key Vault.

Use case: I have a website having a SSL certificate signed by a CA. (Not supported by Azure Key Vault)
I want to have that root certificate in my key vault and generate client certificates as needed for our customers. (They need to be able to validate that the certificate they retrieved, came from our Root Certificate).

My questions:

1 - Am I correct when assuming the following:

I can generate a certificate with the Azure key vault, export the CSR, and get the CSR signed by my CA. Importing the output file provided by my CA, will result in having the correct root certificate stored in the Key Vault.

2 - To generate client certificates, I need to repeat the process described in question 1, however, I do not need to get signed by the CA, but rather by my new certificate that was created above? This way, I can create many client certificates in a secure way.